# How can I decide whether a closed surface is intersected by a triangle?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

A closed surface consisted of `Polygons` or `GraphicsComplex` and a triangle made by 3 points are in a 3D space. How can I decide whether intersected or not. I have tried by using `RegionMember` but It does not work. 
(this code is typed in *version 10*)

```
g1 = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotPoints -> 2];
surface = 
  GraphicsComplex[g1[[1, 1]], {Opacity[0.7], g1[[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1]]}];

triangles = {
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, -1, 2}}],
   Polygon[{{2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, -1, 2}}],
   Polygon[{{-3, 0, -3}, {3, 2, 2}, {-3, -1, 2}}]};
```

examples

```
Grid[{{"Not Intersected", "Inside 1-Point,
   Intersected", "Outside 3-Point,
   Intersected"},
  Table[Graphics3D[{surface, Opacity[0.7], Green, t},
    Boxed -> False], {t, triangles}]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to make a function that is decide whether intesected or not like this:

[image]

I expect like this results.

[image]

**Is there any idea or algorithm paper?**

---

**My Wrong Try**

```
makeSurfaceEq[v_List, {x_, y_, z_}] :=
 Module[{a, b, c, d, eq},
   eq = a x + b y + c z + d == 0;
   eq = eq /. NSolve[(a #1 + b #2 + c #3 + d == 0 &) @@@ v];
   eq = If[eq[[0]] === List, eq[[1]]];
   eq /. {a | b | c | d -> 1}
   ] /; Length[v] >= 3
polygonToSurfaceInEq[v_, f_, {x_, y_, z_}] := Module[{cOfG, eqs, ineq},
  cOfG = Mean@v;
  eqs = makeSurfaceEq[v[[#]], {x, y, z}] & /@ f;
  Table[
    ineq = eqs[[i]] /. Equal -> Greater;
    If[ineq /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> cOfG], ineq, ! ineq],
    {i, Length[eqs]}] /.
   {Greater -> GreaterEqual, Less -> LessEqual}
  ]
```

here is something wrong result. and though a point is in closed surface, **the command**

> polygonToSurfaceInEq

**is not applied for a like torus.**

```
intersectedQ[polygons_, triangle_] := Module[{},
  f = Function @@ {{x, y, z},
     And @@ polygonToSurfaceInEq[
       polygons[[1]],
       Cases[polygons, Polygon[a_] -> a, \[Infinity]][[1]],
       {x, y, z}]
     };
  Or @@ f @@@ triangle[[1]]
  ]
```

my try is this.

```
intersectedQ[surface, triangles[[1]]]
```

> True

3 points are all outside of the surface.

```
intersectedQ[surface, triangles[[2]]]
```

> False

---

**Wrong Try2**
Pickett's answer is good approach but is not a answer of my question. The closed surface is made by polygons and **bounded by polygons surfaces**. The following example show that I mean.

```
intersectQ[polygon_] := With[{distFunc = RegionDistance@Polygon[polygon]}, 
   Length@Select[
      findPossibleIntersections[polygon, surface[[1]], 0.01], 
      distFunc@# < 0.05 &] > 0];
intersectQ@{{1.8, 1.2, 0.9}, {1.5, 1, 2}, {1.5, 2, 2}}
```

> False

This is inside of surface, but this code answer FALSE.

```
Graphics3D[{surface,
  Opacity[.7], Green, 
  Polygon[{{1.8, 1.2, 0.9}, {1.5, 1, 2}, {1.5, 2, 2}}],
  Opacity[1], Red, Point[{1.8, 1.2, 0.9}]},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Oska for considering my question.

Comment: `RegionIntersection` is supposed to do this but it doesn't work for regions embedded in 3D.

Comment: @RunnyKine yes I know about that. I need in 3d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
g1 = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotPoints -> 2];
surface = 
  GraphicsComplex[g1[[1, 1]], {Opacity[0.7], g1[[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1]]}];

triangles = {Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, -1, 2}}], 
   Polygon[{{2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, -1, 2}}], 
   Polygon[{{-3, 0, -3}, {3, 2, 2}, {-3, -1, 2}}],
   Polygon[{{1.8, 1.2, 0.9}, {1.5, 1, 2}, {1.5, 2, 2}}]
   };
```

First we extract and partition the coordinates and polygons.

```
coords = surface[[1]];
ply = Flatten[
   Cases[surface[[2]], _Polygon, Infinity] /. 
    Polygon[data_] :> Partition[data, 1], 1];
```

Load `TetGenLink`

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
```

and write a `test` function that returns a `Graphics3D` with the intersection. It should be easy to adjust this.

```
test[in_] := Module[{nc, maxInci, ninci, res},
  nc = getCoords[in];
  maxInci = Max[ply];
  ninci = {{Range[Length[nc]]}} + maxInci;
  res = TetGenDetectIntersectingFacets[Join[coords, nc], 
    Join[ply, ninci]];
  Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[res[[1]], Polygon[res[[2]]]]]
  ]

getCoords[Polygon[d_]] := N[d];
```

When I run this on your example

```
test /@ triangles
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Öskå, you could `Show` the graphics together.

Comment: @user21 Thank you This is very interesting of TetGenLink`.

Answer (score 1):

First step is turning the `GraphicsComplex` in surface into standard `Polygon`-s:

```
polys = surface // Normal // Flatten;
```

I'll be using `Resolve` further on which doesn't like inaccurate numbers, so I `Rationalize` the coordinates. There are many coordinates that are terribly close to each other, leading to degenerated polygons. I'll remove these:

```
polysClean =  
   DeleteCases[Map[Union[Rationalize[#, .00001]] &, polys, {2}], Polygon[a_] /; Length[a] < 3]
```

Introduce a function that describes a general point on a triangle:

```
triPoint[poly_List, m_, n_] :=
    Module[{l1},
      l1 = m (poly[[3]] - poly[[2]]) + poly[[2]];
      n (l1 - poly[[1]]) + poly[[1]]
]
```

A point is within the triangle if `0 <= n <= 1 && 0 <= m <= 1`. We can now use `Resolve` and `Exists` to find out whether there are surface triangles for which such a general point exists on the test triangle that makes it a `RegionMember` of the surface triangle:

```
intersectionQ[polys_, testPoly_] :=
Or @@ 
(Resolve[
   Exists[{n, m}, 
      0 <= n <= 1 && 0 <= m <= 1 && RegionMember[#, triPoint[testPoly, m, n]]
   ]
 ] & /@  polys)

intersectionQ[polysClean, #] & /@ First /@ triangles
(* {False, True, True} *)
```

By the way, if the torus was defined implicitly, using `ImplicitRegion` it would all be much more easy and faster:

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[1 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 3 && (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 2)^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}]

Resolve[Exists[{n, m}, 0 <= n <= 1 && 0 <= m <= 1 && 
   RegionMember[ℛ, triPoint[{{2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, -1, 2}}, m, n]]]]
(* True *)
```